# DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

Does anyone have the faintest idea what this error means please and how to resolve it?  All my research is drawing a blank, I can see how to set it on MSDN but it doesn't explain it in a way that explains to me what the issue is.  If I remove some of my LINQ queries to set viewbag items then it seems to resolve it but the moment I set new ones and pass them into my view to generate a mail for MVCMailer it comes back.  Not sure if its a viewbag issue or simply that I am calling too many linq queries to generate them to pass to the view.

I am very stuck (again)..........

Cheers,
Steve.

DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument.
Parameter name: argument
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument.
Parameter name: argument

An example of the code is:

```
            var VBSalutation = from A in context.Salutations
                where A.SalutationId == policytransaction.SalutationId
                select A.SalutationName;
        ViewBag.Salutation = VBSalutation.FirstOrDefault();
```

This is repeated for various parameters and then passed to the view.

Comment: Sql Server Compact 4.  If you think this is DBEngine related I could setup an Azure DB and see if I could repeat it?  I thought it was code related so hadn't attempted this.

Comment: it could be, ust wanted to make sure it wasnt mysql related as there were some driver issues at one point. Is this code first or edmx?

Comment: are you calling FirstOrDefault while your context is still in scope?

Comment: I am yes Adam, is that an error?  New context is at the top of the page and then the code like example above is all the way down the page building up the ViewBag and then calls the method at the bottom and returns a mailmessage.  I have now tried this in Azure and I get the same error.

Comment: can you post all the code? I want to see everything going on in your controller also your model as well for salutation. Personally I would use using{var context = new YourContext){ ViewBag.Saluation = ( from A in context.Salutations
                where A.SalutationId == policytransaction.SalutationId
                select A.SalutationName).FirstOrDefault();}  to ensure everything is in the context. I prefer not to use ViewBag and instead use ViewModels, but if this is just a basic basic app then its understandable.

Comment: Hi Adam, this is now fixed.  The main table has several ID's in it, so using salutation as an example it holds the salutationId which you have to lookup in the salutation table to get the text.  What I did originally was open the datacontext at the top and then did one linq query as above for each of the lookups and set the viewbag after each call.  I have fixed it by consolodating my database calls, by doing several joins and then setting the viewbag items within a foreach.  I don't understand why I broke it but less separate queries and doing everything in one call works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I faced a similar problem and solved it. Problem was in WHERE clause: data type of left side equal operator (=) sign was not matching with data type of right side. So in your scenario:

`where A.SalutationId == policytransaction.SalutationId`

SalutationID of A might be an INT and SalutationId of policytransaction might be a string (This is how it was in my case).

I solved it by assigning policytransaction.SalutationId to an Int variable and using it:

```
int myIntVariable = Convert.ToInt16(policytransaction.SalutationId);
...//some code here
where A.SalutationId == myIntVariable;
```

Please also note that you cannot directly cast your variables directly in Linq else you'll get an error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method". You'll have to use a temp variable and then apply the where clause.

Comment: Thanks DonNetFreak, I ended up recoding it as I thought it was the number of calls to the database I was doing so can't easily test this.  It sounds sensible and will help others given I found nothing on this online.  So marked as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ViewBag.Salutation = VBSalutation.SingleOrDefault();`